# how can i integrate TeamUp Calendar

Tags: asp.net, .net, integrate

I am trying to integrate TeamUp calendar with as ASP.NET project.

How can i integrate and create / edit events in Project?
I would like them to reflect on TeamUp calendar and Vice Versa.

Comment: What kind of .NET application do you have? Is it WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET MVC based?

Comment: its ASP.NET project . I need to create / edit events in Project and want them reflect on TeamUp calendar and Vice Versa. if you need more information , let me know.

Comment: Checked [docs](http://apidocs.teamup.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :)

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public string getData(){
var TeamupAPIKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add
                        (new 
  MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add
                ("Teamup-Token", TeamupAPIKey);

            var stringTask = 
  client.GetStringAsync("https://api.teamup.com/ksdtwavnmo6cfqhm4o/keys");
            var msg = await stringTask;

  return msg;
}
```